# Absolute uniform convergence implies uniform convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove or refute:

> Let $f_n(x)$ be sequence of functions. If $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|f_n(x)\right|$ uniformly convergent, then $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$ uniformly convergent.

I thought about Weierstrass M-test and tried to prove the contrapositive claim, but unfortunately nothing seems to work. I tried to find a counter-example, but to no avail. I believe that the claim is true.

How should someone tackle this one?

Thanks!

Comment: Your functions $f_i$ are functions $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with no further restrictions?

Comment: @Marc, $f_i:I\to\mathbb{R}$ as $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, so I assume that we can take $f_i:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with no restrictions.

Comment: I think some functions are uniformly convergent on any interval but not on $\mathbb{R}$, so that would be problematic

Comment: @vrugtehagel, we can take $I$ to be any segment.

Comment: Hint: Cauchy is your friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Cauchy Criterion for uniform convergence: a series converges uniformly iff $|∑_m^n f_i(x)|$ can be made arbitrarily small for all x at once by making $m,n>N$ for some $N$.

Comment: May I write $\displaystyle \left|\sum_{n=1}^{N}|f_n(x)|-\sum_{n=1}^{M}|f_n(x)|\right|=\left|\sum_{n=M}^{N}|f_n(x)|\right|=\sum_{n=M}^{N}|f_n(x)|<\varepsilon$, thus $f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent by Cauchy criterion?

Comment: Yes, exactly, except the last equality should be an inequality.